# Url.Action return the current link in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, url.action

I am currently on the page `/Customer/Edit/13244`.

When I use `@Url.Action("Edit", "Customer")` on the same page it returns me `/Customer/Edit/13244`, but I want it to return `/Customer/Edit/`.

Kindly tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: why do you need to see Controller Code?

Comment: you don't want id in url right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use (assuming your using the default route with `id = UrlParameter.Optional`

```
@Url.Action("Edit", "Customer", new { id = "" })
```

Comment: Yes i am currently using what u have suggested but i thought thats not a proper solution :P

Comment: You need to do that because the value is automatically added to the route parameters by the UrlHelper

Comment: @WaqarAhmed sometimes you need to tweak with proper solutions

Answer (score 3):

This is a "feature" of MVC that many people find unnatural and [was previously reported as a bug](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346).

Microsoft's official response:

> Ultimately if you want the most control over what gets generated for a URL there are a few options to consider:
>
> 1. Use named routes to ensure that only the route you want will get used to generate the URL (this is often a good practice, though it won't help in this particular scenario)
> 2. Specify all route parameters explicitly - even the values that you want to be empty. That is one way to solve this particular problem.
> 3. Instead of using Routing to generate the URLs, you can use Razor's ~/ syntax or call Url.Content("~/someurl") to ensure that no extra (or unexpected) processing will happen to the URL you're trying to generate.

Actually, this bug only rears its ugly head when you try to re-purpose an action method name. If you use a different action method name other than `Edit` in the case where it is not followed by `id`, this problem will magically disappear.